# Smart way to on/off print() in the function

Tags: python

I want to use standard output if a `function()` have args `use_standard_output = True`.

Like this:

```
def function(use_standard_output = True):

    ~ SOME PROCESS ~

    if(use_standard_output):
        print("print something to monitor the process")
```

Is there smarter way to implement this?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if `use_standard_output = False`? Does it do nothing or does it write to a log file?

Answer (score 3):

Look into the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) module. It comes equipped with different levels.

For example, you could replace your call to `print` with `logging.info("Print something to monitor the process")`

If you configure it with `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`, you will see the output. If you raise the logging level (e.g. `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)`, it will be ignored.

For a complete example:

```
import logging
def function():
    logging.info("print something to monitor the process")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
function()
logging.basicConfig(leve=logging.WARNING)
function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's "smart" or not, you can redefine the print function. This was the rationale for making it a function in Python 3. Since you'll be "shadowing" the built-in function (i.e. re-using its name locally, effectively redefining it) you do, of course, have to retain a reference to the built_in function so you can use it inside your redefinition.

Then a global (here, `OUTPUT_REQUIRED`) can determine whether or not it produces any output:

```
system_print = print

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    if OUTPUT_REQUIRED:
        system_print(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `*args, *kwargs` notation may not be familiar to you. Using it as the code does, in both the definition and the call, it is a simple way to call `system_print` with the same positional and keyword arguments that your `print` function was called with.

You could continue to use the additional argument by explicitly naming it in the definition, and not passing it through to `print`:

```
system_print = print

def print(OUTPUT_REQUIRED, *args, **kwargs):
    if OUTPUT_REQUIRED:
        system_print(*args, **kwargs)
```

This represents a change to the API which would make switching back to the standard function more difficult. I'd recommend simply using a different name in this case.

The logging module, while extremely comprehensive, takes a little more effort to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want either write the message to the terminal or to a log file you can work with streams. You simply work with a stream object pointing to a file or STDOUT.

```
import sys

if use_standard_output:
    stream = sys.stdout
else:
    stream = open('logfile', 'w')

print("print something to monitor the process", file=stream)
```